# Getting Cannot GET / in NodeJS Express project

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I've tried numerous methods to solve this from `app.use(express.static(__dirname + "public"))` to `res.render` and it works in my terminal but not in my local host. Where am I going wrong?
Here's my JS file:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var fs = require ('fs');
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
//
app.get('/index', function (req, res) {
res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "index.html" );
})
//app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
//app.get('/index.html', (request, response) =>  response.sendFile( __dirname, "/index.html"));
app.post('/userinfo', (request, response) => {
const postBody = request.body;
console.log(postBody);
response.send(postBody);
});
app.listen(3002, () => console.info('Application running on port 3002'));
```

And here's my HTML file:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Express - Node.js POST data example</title>
  </head>
   <body>
    <form action="/userinfo" method="POST">
      Some data: <input type="text" name="data" id="data">
   <button type="submit">Send</button>
   </form>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: well you don't seem to have a route called `/`, you have `/index` and `/userinfo`, how do you expect to GET an unexciting route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no response for **base url** or `/` route is defined. You have defined only two routes and I assume `/index` for your index page. So, the page will be render at `localhost:3002/index` . You have to define another response for `/` or **base url** like,

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "index.html" );
})
```

Hopefully, your problem will be solved.